How to create a code to generate a HAR file from Raw request/response
I create a small transparent proxy based in Titanium, but really my goal is be able to get the request and response to create a HAR file.
I made a search for the web, but not found any contribution, package or something that allow me to made the HAR creation.
The proxy is done in C# NET 8.0 and the planning is using the code only in Windows Machine.
Someone know something that can help me?
Thanks in Advance.
